# credentials:edit caused VIM: Caught deadly signal SEGV on Rails 5.2.beta

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, vim

Trying out Rails 5.2.beta2

When I type `bin/rails credentials:edit`, the following error occurred:

```
Your Ruby version is 2.0.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.4.2
Vim: Caught deadly signal SEGV
Vim: Finished.
New credentials encrypted and saved.
```

I use rbenv and have set the global version to be 2.4.2. I guess the 2.0.0 comes from system Ruby.

If I use `EDITOR=nano` then it works as expected.

Mac OS X version: El Capitan.
Vim version: 7.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems my VIM is too old. I used homebrew to install a Vim version 8.0.1400.

```
brew install vim
```

Then I close the console and reopen it. Now it works properly.

It still alerts about ruby versions: `Your Ruby version is 2.4.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.4.2`